# how to add, remove, or update properties inside application.properties using spring cloud config server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config-server

There is an endpoint in the config server to read all properties inside a properties file, like this:

GET http://localhost:8080/< properties name >/default
[image: the rsponse]

**Is there a way to create a new source property in application-local.properties file using Postman or using java code?**

[image]